# CodeIgniter: 404 error causing a 500/Routes not valid error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm having a strange problem. I'm getting a 500 error for some pages (that don't exist and I'm trying them just to cause a 404 error and test this) when I try to cause an error, and then sometimes I get the actual 404 error page.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] AddHandler cgi-script .pl
```

Could this be causing this? Anyone have a thought as to what could cause this?  I have my base_url set to the proper domain.  The problem seems to revolve around either the RewriteEngine and RewriteBase lines, but I can't figure out how to configure them. The issue doesn't seem to be in my routes.  If I comment out all of them except the default controller and the 404_override, I still get the same error:

`Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.`

Comment: You get the apache 404, or the CodeIgniter 404?

Comment: I don't get either.  I get a "routes not valid" message.  I have a 404_override set to one of my controllers.

Comment: What URL/controller are you trying to reach and what do your routes look like?

Comment: I'm trying to get controllers that do not exist rerouted to the 404_override controller.

Comment: Can we see what your $routes array looks like? At least those that pertain to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your config file have you made sure to set the $config['base_url'] to '' ? That is needed when using clean urls.

Another thing to try would be to set your $config['log_threshold'] to 4 as then you could start seeing where exactly the error is coming into play.

Just for reference here is a known good .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|humans\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should check route config `$route['default_controller']=valid controller`. if this did not cause error then you might change your .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```